# WF. C# expressions inside of NativeActivity

Tags: expression, workflow-foundation

I am trying to use custom c# expression inside of NativeActivity

It works fine with simple expression like *Condition = new CSharpValue("1 == 1")*

It doesn't work with such expressions *Condition = new CSharpValue("Address == null")*

I cannot refer to the activity's Variable or InArgument in the expression due to expression compilation error "The name 'xxxxx' does not exist in the current context"

**Working code**

```
var act = new ExecuteIfTrue
{
    Condition = new CSharpValue<Boolean>("1 == 1"),
    Address = new InArgument<MailAddress>(ctx => new MailAddress { DisplayName = "TestDisplayName" }),
    Body = new WriteLine { Text = "Rest!" }
};

CompileCSharpExpressions<MailAddress>(act);
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(act);
```

**Non-Working code (refers to the InArgument of NativeActivity)**

```
var act = new ExecuteIfTrue
{
    Condition = new CSharpValue<Boolean>("Address.Email == null"),
    //Condition = new CSharpValue<Boolean>("MailAddressVar == null"),
    Address = new InArgument<MailAddress>(ctx => new MailAddress { DisplayName = "TestDisplayName" }),
    Body = new WriteLine { Text = "Rest!" }
};

CompileCSharpExpressions<MailAddress>(act);
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(act);
```

**NativeActivity**

```
public class ExecuteIfTrue : NativeActivity
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<bool> Condition { get; set; }

    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<MailAddress> Address { get; set; }

    public Variable<MailAddress> MailAddressVar;

    public Activity Body { get; set; }

    public ExecuteIfTrue()
    {
        MailAddressVar = new Variable<MailAddress> { Default = null };
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        if (context.GetValue(this.Condition) && this.Body != null)
            context.ScheduleActivity(this.Body);
    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AddImplementationVariable(MailAddressVar);
        base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
    }
}


public class MailAddress
{
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

**Helper method**

```
public static void CompileCSharpExpressions<T>(Activity activity)
{
    var impl = new AttachableMemberIdentifier(typeof(TextExpression), "NamespacesForImplementation");
    var namespaces = new List<string> { typeof(T).Namespace };
    TextExpression.SetReferencesForImplementation(activity, new AssemblyReference { Assembly = typeof(T).Assembly });
    AttachablePropertyServices.SetProperty(activity, impl, namespaces);

    var activityName = activity.GetType().ToString();
    var activityType = activityName.Split('.').Last() + "_CompiledExpressionRoot";
    var activityNamespace = string.Join(".", activityName.Split('.').Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse());

    var settings = new TextExpressionCompilerSettings
    {
        Activity = activity,
        Language = "C#",
        ActivityName = activityType,
        ActivityNamespace = activityNamespace,
        RootNamespace = null,
        GenerateAsPartialClass = false,
        AlwaysGenerateSource = true,
        ForImplementation = false
    };

    var results = new TextExpressionCompiler(settings).Compile();

    if (results.HasErrors)
    {
        throw new Exception("Compilation failed.");
    }

    var compiledExpressionRoot = Activator.CreateInstance(results.ResultType, new object[] { activity }) as ICompiledExpressionRoot;
    CompiledExpressionInvoker.SetCompiledExpressionRoot(activity, compiledExpressionRoot);
}
```

Comment: What you are expecting to happen is for the workflow runtime to somehow understand that the string "Address" refers to the name of an InArgument. 

I'm assuming that you want to be able to execute some external code withing the runtime. For this I would look at either passing in an Activity or an ActivityDelegate as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty explicit; your expression does not have the variable `MailAddressVar` in scope.

The reason being is you need to pass the variable into the expression. The `ExecuteIfTrue` activity does not have a variables parameter.

**Instead try something like this:**

```
Variable<string> mailAddressVar = new Variable<string>(name: "MailAddressVar", defaultValue: null);

Activity seq = new Sequence
{
    Variables = { mailAddressVar },
    Activities = 
    {
        new ExecuteIfTrue
        {       
            //Condition = new CSharpValue<Boolean>("Address.Email == null"),
            Condition = new CSharpValue<Boolean>("MailAddressVar == null"),
            Address = new InArgument<MailAddress>(ctx => new MailAddress { DisplayName = "TestDisplayName" }),
            Body = new WriteLine { Text = "Rest!" }
        }
    }
};

ExecuteIfTrue.CompileCSharpExpressions<MailAddress>(seq);
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(seq);
```